# How do I search and group by a date column into sets of duration ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, group-by

I have a table like this;

`jobID  - jobTitle - jobCreatedDate`

I want to make it possible for visitors to search in Jobs table and list it by grouping like this and I want to do it with just one SQL query:

```
Date Added
- AnyTime (20)
- 1 day ago (5)
- 2-7 days ago (2)
- 8-14 days ago (0)
- 15-30 days ago (7)
```

I tried Group By "jobCreatedDate" with no success and I couldn't understand the logic of the necessary query.

Here is an example what I'm trying to do:

[image: Here is an example]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the date difference between `today` and the field `JobCreated`. Then based on the difference in the value days, you need to classify the output accordingly into various categories to meet your requirements.

I hope that is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT  SUM(1)  AS [AnyTime]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN DayCount = 1                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [1 day ago]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN DayCount BETWEEN 2 AND 7      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [2-7 days ago]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN DayCount BETWEEN 8 AND 14     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [8-14 days ago]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN DayCount BETWEEN 15 AND 30    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [15-30 days ago]
FROM    
(
    SELECT      JobID
            ,   DATEDIFF(d, JobCreatedDate, GETDATE()) AS DayCount
    FROM        dbo.Jobs
) Jobs
```

Screenshot shows sample data and the query output.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEADD tsql method.

```
Select ...
From [Table]
Where JobCreatedDate between DATEADD(dd, @NumDays, GetDate()) and GetDate()
```

In this query @NumDays is a parameter representing the number of days to subtract from the current date.  Make sure you pass a negative number to the query.  If you are trying to create non inclusive ranges, you'll need to use two DATEADD calls passing two parameters to the query.

EDIT
I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  This may not be the most elegant solution, but you could accomplish your goal using a union query.

```
Select sum(OneDay) as OneDay, sum(SevenDays) as SevenDays
From
 (select 1 as OneDay, 0 as SevenDays
  From [table]
  Where JobCreatedDate between DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate()) and GetDate())
  UNION
 (select 0 as OneDay, 1 as SevenDays
  From[table]
  Where JobCreatedDate between DATEADD(dd, -7, GetDate()) and DATEADD(dd, -2, GetDate()))
```

Comment: thanks but your query only selects data between 1 date. I know how to select data between start and end date but I need to select counts of data between multiple dates with one query. I think I should use CASE or, I don't know :)

For example; First select count of data between today and 1 week ago, and then 1 week ago and 2 weeks ago and so on. After that group the results by data count from higher to lower.